# Nodejs child_process spawn with $ variable

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

Question: Can I access $variable via `{spawn} = require("child_process")` ?

Background: I have already tried using `exec("echo $HOME");` which output the correct value.

But when I tried to use `spawn("echo",["$HOME"])`, I got `$HOME`

And how to define the variable by using `spawn`? Currently I'm setting the child_process option `{env:{data:1000}}`, is this correct or not ?

Comment: try without the `env` option. Is it printing the value or `$HOME`?

Comment: `'$HOME'` @vibhor1997a

Answer (score 0):

by default, `spawn` does not create a shell and then execute the command within that shell (as appose to `exec` which starts a shell first and then executes the command within that shell).

Since there is no shell, the "$HOME" environment variable is not set. You can set `spawn` to execute the command within a shell:

```
spawn("echo",["$HOME", { shell: true });
```